# How to get the ID of element by matching name in mongoDB by Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get ID by a matching name in mongoDB in Java.

That's my code:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
        DBCollection groupTable = db.getCollection("Items");

        searchQuery.put("name", "John");

          DBCursor cursor = groupTable.find(searchQuery);
          while (cursor.hasNext()) {
              System.out.println(cursor.next());
          }
```

But it shows the whole row containt the name John, what I want is the ID not the whole thing.

```
{"list":[{"timestamp":{"$date":"2014-08-01T08:37:54.058Z"},"name":John,"_id":{"$oid":"53db5045ccf2b2399e0e6128"},"created":{"$date":"2014-08-}
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, just select the id...

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next().get("_id"));
}
```